# Control a script that runs at start-up through SSH

Tags: command-line, server, ssh

So I have a server running that runs a few scripts automatically at start-up. They run a few programs that allow you to execute commands from them.

This has been going fine but now I am wondering if it is possible to then look at these instances of programs through a shell. How do I get to the instance running it from my command-line?

I connect via SSH and the server is running a server OS.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can see the list of running programs after you ssh by running [top](http://linux.die.net/man/1/top) or [ps](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ps).

The set of programs run at startup is usually found in `.profile` or `/etc/profile`. 
If the ssh shell runs bash `.bash_profile` or `.bash_rc` or `/etc/bashrc` may also contain instructions to run the programs.

More detailed information about services is found in `sudo service --status-all`